# LESS CSS preprocessor: Is there a way to map a single color to an rgb and rgba definition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, less

I'm trying to write a block in the CSS preprocessor LESS that will do the following:

```
@transparent_background(@color; @alpha: .8)
{
  background: @color;
  background: rgba(<color R value>, <color G value>, <color B value>, @alpha);
}
```

Is there any way to get the RGB values out of @color if it's a standard hex definition (i.e. #rrggbb)? Is there a way to do this if @color is defined some other way?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

```
@transparent_background(@color; @alpha: .8)
{
  background: @color;
  background: @color + rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the solutions work anymore, but this one does (thanks to [@Elyse](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5176868/89771)):

```
.alpha(@color, @alpha: 0.8) {
    color: @color;
    color: hsla(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color), @alpha);
}
```

The `hsla()` function, while not advertised in the LESS website, is defined [in the source code](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/blob/ddc27617cf3f576b260df1ec78c84262699cc109/lib/less/functions.js#L15).

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
background: @color - rgba(0, 0, 0, 1.0) + rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
```

The subtraction will clear the alpha channel on `@color` then you just add the desired `@alpha` to the alpha channel. Colors have the full suite of operators and they work component by component when operating on two colors; colors are stored as RGBA components internally so this should work. Also, the alpha channel is normalized to be in the interval `[0, 1.0]` so subtracting 1.0 from the alpha channel should clear it without causing any problems.

I don't have CSS LESS set up right now so I can't check but this is worth a shot.

Comment: Since @color is just a hex definition, there's no need to subtract the alpha channel first. So the solution was simply: @color + rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha). Seems obvious in retrospect but I didn't realize you could mix hex/rgba like that.

Comment: I was just being a bit paranoid and trying to future-proof the alpha channel modification, hence the subtraction to force the alpha channel into a known state so that adding `@alpha` to it would result in the alpha channel being equal to `@alpha`. As an added bonus it makes it clearer that you're assigning the alpha channel rather than just adjusting it a bit.

Comment: In lessphp at least, there's no check to prevent the alpha channel from going negative.

Comment: Really? I'd fix it and submit a patch if I was using lessphp. A negative alpha doesn't make much sense (maybe "press really really really hard with the black crayon"?) and the canonical Ruby implementation limits the alpha to `[0,1]`. OTOH, this demonstrates the problem of working without a formal specification.

Answer (score 2):

Note that you can also proceed with the fadein/fadeout functions of LESS :

```
.alpha(@color, @alpha: 80)
{
    background-color: fadeout(@color, (100 - @alpha));
}
```

Thus, **.alpha(red, 25)** will result in a background-color of **rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25)**

Comment: +1, Nice one! PS: I absolutely love the new LESS guarded mixins. :D

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but if all you are looking to do is add an alpha value just use `fade(@color, @alpha)`. Color can be in hex, rgba or hsla.