# LESScss converting rgba to hex? how to nest color variables into a mixin?

Tags: css, colors, rgba, less

Does LESScss convert all rgba colors to hex values?

I am trying to create a mixin, say, .color, that allows you to pass in a color variable previously defined, and I want it to be in rgba.

this doesn't work, but here's the idea:

```
.bgcolor(@colorvariable,@alpha) {
     background-color: @colorvariable + rgba(0, 0, 0, @alpha);
     }
```

Where `@colorvariable` would be, `@blue: rgb(17,55,76);` or `@green: rgb(125,188,83);` etc.

I want to define a bunch of these variables, and then be able to pass them in to `.bgcolor` or `.color` mixin and change the alpha transparency on the fly.

I feel like this should be possible, but I am missing something. -Right now, my code only ever outputs a hex color value, almost no matter what I input.- If I pass in an @alpha value of 1, it outputs a hex color value. Only @alpha values less than 1 force the browser to show me an rgba value. So that's solved.

Now--how to pass in the rgb and a parts separately from a predefined variable?

Answer (score 26):

Turns out, less has hsla functions built in (see [less color functions](http://lesscss.org/#-color-functions)). So with some help, here's what we discovered:

```
    @dkblue: #11374c;
    .colorize_bg(@color: @white, @alpha: 1) {
           background: hsla(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color), @alpha);}
```

Then use the mixin:

```
section {.colorize_bg(@dkblue,1);}
```

So we pass in the color variable `@dkblue` and less' functions like `hue(@color)` take `@dkblue` and pull out its hue, saturation, and lightness values. We can then pass in an alpha that we define in that mixin.

Then I can use it in other ways, like to define transparent borders. By adding `background-clip: padding-box;` to `.colorize_bg` I ensure that my borders show outside of the bg box color (isn't CSS3 magical?) Then I can redefine the mixin to work for border color:

```
    .colorize_border(@color: @white, @alpha: 1) {border-color: hsla(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color), @alpha);}
```

and then give `section` the border width, style, and define color via the mixin:

```
section {border-width: 0 10px; border-style: solid; .colorize_border(@dkblue, .5);
```

And you'll get magical, shiny transparent borders, like so: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jSKR.png

Comment: +1 Nice workout! 
Didn't know about hue(), saturation() an lightness() functions.

Comment: Thanks! We both have my boyfriend to thank, who a) thinks like a programmer, and b) reads the manual :P

Answer (score 19):

LESS has a set of functions to `fade`, `fadeIn`, or `fadeOut` a color. You should be able to pass any color to these mixins (hsl, rgb, rgba, hex, etc.)

```
// fade color to 40%
color: fade(#000000, 40);

// fade in color by 10%
color: fadeIn(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 10);

// fade out color by 10%
color: fadeOut(rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), 10);
```

Comment: The answer is correct. Just not sure why one would use a mixin in this case? as the function basically does the exact same thing.

Comment: @marcjae - you are right. I'm not sure why I wrapped them in mixins.  I was still kinda new to LESS at the time.  I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 8):

You don't need to convert to hsla either so you won't need a white value

```
.hexBackgroundToRGBA(@color,@alpha){
  @myred:red(@color);
  @mygreen:green(@color);
  @myblue:blue(@color);
  background-color: @color;
  background-color: rgba(@myred,@mygreen,@myblue,@alpha);
}
```

You'll have to write a few of these mixins in you need to set stuff other than the background-color property set but that's the idea.  Just call it like this:

```
#selector{  .hexBackgroundToRGBA(@gray, 0.8); }
```

That will take whatever color val you have in the @gray variable and output a cross browser solution at 80% transparency with a solid color fallback for browsers that don't support rgba().

Comment: Was this included prior to the 1.4 beta?

Comment: I have to say that this seems to be the more elegant solution, and closer to the OP's question.

Comment: How about this error I got? `error evaluating function 'red': Cannot read property '0' of undefined`